# Okular doesn't allow me to do reviews on certain pdfs

Tags: linux, pdf-reader

As the title says I found a particular pdf in wich okular's review function is not working. Whenever I press F the review menu doesn't show, and by trying to access it via tools -> menu it looks like the function is disabled. Why does this happen in a particular pdf (all other pdfs I've read in okular didn't have this problem).

Comment: Okular now offers an option to edit DRM-locked pdfs as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/920625/609564). So, the other two answers are now obsolete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that there are PDF's that have flags that set them as readonly. Use

```
pdf2ps foo.pdf; ps2pdf foo.ps foo.pdf
```

This uses Ghostscript to print the PDF into Postscript and then back into PDF, thus circumventing the readonly mechanism.

Comment: After this transformation review works. However, I was not able to search in or copy text from the new pdf. I recommend the solution of Todd Blumer

Answer (score 24):

new123456's answer works, I used this method for a long time. The problem I found however was that in the translation from pdf to ps to pdf, the pdf's metadata and bookmarks were lost. A solution that doesn't lose this data:

```
$ qpdf -decrypt readonly.pdf editable.pdf
```

If you can read readonly.pdf without a password, but simply can't edit (or okular review) it, this will give you an editable copy of that file.

Comment: You can do the same thing with pdftk: `pdftk readonly.pdf output editable.pdf`. They even give you a message explaining to "please respect the copyright"...

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue with a pdf, Motorola 68000 Programmer's Reference Manual.

You shouldn't need to modify the pdf. To overcome this issue you only need to untick a checkbox in the settings. Go:

*Settings* -> *Configure Okular...*

Now untick **Obey DRM limitations** under *Program Features* in the *General* tab.

Click *OK* and restart Okular. You can now review the pdf like any other.